# DirectX11 and packetoffset

Tags: algorithm, rendering, hlsl, directx-10, directx-11

Does anyone know how to use "packetoffset" with a bool type in DirectX10/11? I am not sure how this should be aligned

```
cbuffer SomeBuffer : register( b1 )
{
    float3 SomeFloat3: packoffset(c0);
    float SomeFloat: packoffset(c0.w);

    float3 SomeFloat32: packoffset(c1);
    float2 SomeFloat2; ??

    bool SomeBool1; ??
    bool SomeBool2; ??
    bool SomeBool3; ??
}
```

Comment: just don't pack it. it is not mandatory.

Comment: I know it is not necessary, but I want to know how it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually two questions:

1. What happens if you use a `packoffset` that results in a variable extending beyond the bounds of a single register?
2. How do you use `packoffset` with `bool` values?

The answer to the first question is: The HLSL compiler will do some validation on the `packoffset` values. So the following will *not* compile, because `Var2` can't fit in to `c0`, and the compiler will not automatically "wrap" it into `c1`:

```
cbuffer SomeBuffer : register( b1 )
{
    float3 Var1 : packoffset(c0);
    float2 Var2 : packoffset(c0.w); // will not compile
}
```

The answer to the second question is: `bool` values take the same space as a `float`, so you can pack them like this:

```
cbuffer SomeBuffer : register( b1 )
{
    bool SomeBool1 : packoffset(c0);
    bool SomeBool2 : packoffset(c0.y);
    float SomeFloat1 : packoffset(c0.z);
    bool SomeBool3 : packoffset(c0.w);
}
```